# Symfony3 - Error with my method getDomain()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with my method getDomain() becuase I got report ,,Call to a member function getDomain() on null''

This is my Entity ....

```
class Clinic
{
    .............

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $domain;



..............

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDomain()
    {
        return $this->domain;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $domain
     */
    public function setDomain($domain)
    {
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

...............
```

And this is my EventListener

```
 public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $currentHost = $request->getHttpHost();

        $c = $this->em
            ->getRepository('Mybundle:Clinic')
            ->findOneBy(['domain' => $currentHost]);

        if (!$c) {
            $c = $this->em
                ->getRepository('Mybundle:Clinic')
                ->findOneBy(['domain' => $this->baseHost]);
        }

        $this->router->getContext()->setParameter('_domain', $c->getDomain());

        $this->cManager->setCC($c);
```

I have date in my database, please help me.

Comment: `getRepository('Mybundle')` - class name should be passed `getRepository('Mybundle:Clinic')`

Comment: Yes of, course. I wrote getRepository('MyBundle') that write shorter. .

Comment: have you tried applying your logic only for [master requests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types), e.g. like wrapping your logic in `if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
`?

Answer (score 0):

If `$c` is setted in your first call, variable called `$clinic` is never setted, but used in router call.